# Time Complexity of for loop?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

```
p = 0
for(i=1;p<=n;i++){
 p = p+i;
}
```

How can I analyze the time complexity of this loop?
I read that it's O(n^(1/2)). But How?

Comment: Review this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm

Comment: Where did you read that it's O(n^(1/2))?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

How is p increasing? First we add 1, then 2, then 3... then k.

So at step k, p = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k. The [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn) for this is k * (k + 1) / 2. Now, how many steps are needed to reach n?

Let´s try replacing k for sqrt(2n). We have from the formula, sqrt(2n) * (sqrt(2n) + 1) / 2. This is equal to 2n + sqrt(2n) / 2. This is equal to n + some constant. So in sqrt(2n) iterations, we have already reached p > n. This gives us an upper bound of O(sqrt(2n)) which is the same as O(sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 0):

```
p = 0
for(i=1;p<=n;i++){
 p = p+i;
}
```

For every iteration you are adding a 1 no. higher than previous

```
step 1 : p = p + 1;
step 2 : p = p + 2;
step 3 : p = p + 3;
step 4 : p = p + 4;
.....
.....
step m : p = p + m;
```

Your condition is compare the p with n

```
p<=n
```

Sum of values you are adding in p will be like

```
1+2+3+.....+m <= n
```

In Maths, Equation to solve above Sum will be like

```
(m * (m + 1))/2 <= n
```

So, the final complexity reaches to